# Properties of the vector which maximizes $||Ax||_1$ for $A$ invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, orthogonality

I am trying to solve this part of a problem from an old qualification exam, and I am stuck.

> Let $A:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be invertible, let $\mathbb{S}^2$ be the unit sphere and let
>
> $$M = \left\{x\in\mathbb{S}^2 : {\lVert Ax\rVert}_1=\max_{u\,\in\,\mathbb{S}^2}\, {\lVert Au\rVert}_1\right\}.$$
>
> Choose some $v_1\in M$ and let
>
> $$N_1 = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^3 : |x_1| = |x_2| = |x_3| = 1\}.$$
>
> Show that there is some $n_1 \in N_1$ such that for any $x_1 \perp v_1$, we have $n_1 \perp Ax_1$.

Here is what I am trying:
the $n_1$ we are looking for satisfies $\langle n_1, Ax_1\rangle = 0$.
So I re-wrote this as $\langle A^T n_1, x_1\rangle = 0$.
Since we know $\langle v_1, x_1\rangle = 0$, it seems like a good candidate for $n_1$ is the solution to $A^Tn_1 = v_1$.

Since $A$ is invertible, this gives a candidate $n_1$. But now I have to check $n_1 \in N_1$, and I am not sure how to do this. Is this possible? Is there some intuition for what $v_1$ is that could help? Or is there just a simpler way of seeing this?

Answer (score 1):

**Lemma.** Let $\mathbf 1=(1,1,1)^T$ and let $u,v,w,x$ be four vectors such that $v,w,x\ne0,\ x\perp v$ and $\|u+tw\|_1=\|u\|+t\|w\|_1$ for all small $t>0$. Then when $t>0$ is sufficiently small,
$$
\frac{\|u+tw\|_1}{\|v+tx\|_2} > \frac{\|u\|_1}{\|v\|_2}.
$$
*Proof.* Omitted. I shall leave this as an exercise for you.

We may now provide a sketch of proof by contrapositive. First, since $A$ is invertible, $v_1$ must be entrywise nonzero, or else we may use the above lemma to prove that a larger objective function value is attainable at some vector of the form $v_1\pm A^{-1}e_j$ (where $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb R^3$).

So, we may further assume that $Av_1$ is entrywise *positive*. Pick $n_1=(1,1,1)^T$ and let $x_1\perp v_1$. If, contrary to the problem's assertion, that $Ax_1$ is not orthogonal to $n_1$, flip the direction of $x_1$ if necessary to make $\langle Ax_1,n_1\rangle>0$. Now it suffices to show that
$$
\frac{\|Av_1+tAx_1\|_1}{\|v_1+tx_1\|_2} > \frac{\|Av_1\|_1}{\|v_1\|_2}
$$
for all sufficiently small $t>0$.

Denote the projection onto the span of $n_1$ by $P_{n_1}$. Since $Av_1>0$, so is $Av_1+tAx_1$ when $t$ is small. It follows that $\|Av_1+tAx_1\|_1=\|P_{n_1}(Av_1+tAx_1)\|_1=\|P_{n_1}(Av_1)\|_1+t\|P_{n_1}(Ax_1)\|_1$. Now we can use the lemma again to complete the proof.